# Generating traffic statistics from apache access log

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following lines of log say,

`"[123456] /stream 200", "[45678] /chatty 200", "[123456] /stream 400", "[123456] /text 200"`

I need to generate the traffic statistics (as to which endpoint is hit most per second). In this case output would be.

```
123456  /stream
45678   /chatty
```

I have written the following code in Java . Bascially my data structure represents `{"Timestamp": {"endpoint" : count}}`.

```
public class LogParser {


    private static void solve(String [] lines) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> urlMap = null;
        int size = lines.length;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            String [] data = lines[i].split(" ");
            if (map.containsKey(data[0])) {
                urlMap = map.get(data[0]);
            } else {
                urlMap = new HashMap<>();
            }
            if (urlMap.containsKey(data[1])) {
                urlMap.put(data[1], urlMap.get(data[1])+1);
            } else {
                urlMap.put(data[1], 1);
            }
            map.put(data[0], urlMap);
        }
        System.out.println(map.toString());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String [] lines = {"[123456] /stream 200", "[45678] /chatty 200", "[123456] /stream 400", "[123456] /text 200"};
            solve(lines);
    }
}
```

Now to get the to the correct answer I need to sort my urlMap by values. How can I do that ? Is there any other good approach here.

Comment: The timestamp is not needed to know which endpoint is called the most. Just use a Map<String, Integer> where the key is the endpoint and the value is the count, then put the entries of the map in a List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>, and sort that list (or just find the max value, if that's all you need).

Comment: I need the timestamp beacuse I need to group the endpoints count by timestamp.

Comment: So you need, for every distinct timestamp, the endpoint that is called the most? The principle would be the same, except you would have several maps (one per timestamp), and you would find the max entry for each of these maps.